# Why is Ubuntu.com notifying that they use cookies?

Tags: ubuntu-website, cookie

Over the past few days, I've noticed a fixed banner on the header of [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com) that states the following:

[image: We use cookies to help optimise our website. Continued use of our website without having changed your settings confirms your acceptance of these cookies. For details of how to change your settings, please see our privacy policy.]

Did Canonical or Ubuntu have legal or ethical issues with cookies lately? I haven't seen a site notify that blatantly that they use cookies since ~1999.

Comment: [Blame the UK](http://blog.silktide.com/2011/05/cookie-law-makes-most-uk-websites-illegal-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: @jrg Wow! Glad I work in the US.

Comment: They also have been consolidating documents all over the place, so it's entirely possible that this is unrelated to the UK cookie law, and is instead related to their consolidation efforts. But if I had to guess, it'd be the UK cookie law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [new EU cookie law](http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx), all websites must have the consent of the visitors to store information about them.

See also:

- [Why are websites suddenly asking me about cookies?](https://superuser.com/questions/454757/why-are-websites-suddenly-asking-me-about-cookies)